# Delete old divs if there are more than 20 | jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need some help with my jQuery script.
I have a page that refreshes every 10 seconds and new divs from a feed are getting appended at.

My script counts the divs and removes the last div when there are more than 20 divs. This works fine if the feed just appends 1 div at a time. But the feed can also append multiply divs at the same time. When this happens the count can exceed the max of 20 divs. The problem with this is that my script just deletes 1 div and not all the divs that exceed the 20 count.

This is my code:

```
var $auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
    var $articleCount = $('div').length; 

    if ($articleCount > 20) {
        $('div:last-child').remove();
    }

    $autoUpdate();
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds for new items
```

I need to remove all extra divs so there are always 20 divs. I hope someone can help me out with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var $auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
    var $articleCount = $('div').length; 

    while ($articleCount > 20) {
        $('div:last-child').remove();
        $articleCount = $('div').length;
    }

    $autoUpdate();
}, 10000);
```

Notice the change of `if` to `while`. This keeps deleting the last one until there are 20.

Comment: This wouldn't work because `$articlecount` doesn't actually update during the `while` ;)

Comment: sorry, I thought this was the case for [HTMLCollection being live](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-75708506) - didn't notice you made its length a separate variable

Comment: That's a whole load of extra processing going on there :P Even just making the loop evaluate `$('div').length` each time will save you 2 assignment operations, although it's still doing way more than necessary :)

Comment: I never said this was *the* way to do it, just one way, and an easy one at that.

Answer (score 7):

Use jQuery.slice to get everything past number 20, and bin them - dead easy :)

```
var $auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
    $('div').slice(20).remove();
    $autoUpdate();
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds for new items
```

http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`.slice(x)`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to remove all elements from index `x` and on: http://jsfiddle.net/PLKAm/.

```
$("div").slice(20).remove();
```

If there are `<= 20` items then `.slice(20)` returns an empty set, so the code is a no-op automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [greater than](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector:

```
var $auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {

    $('div:gt(20)').remove();

    $autoUpdate();
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds for new items
```

Comment: wouldn't he need to update `$articleCount` within the loop body?

Comment: `:gt` is a jQuery filter, so using it as part of your selector will stop jQuery using the CSS engine to select the divs, which means a performance hit. Better to go with `$('div').filter(':gt(20)')`, or something similar (`.slice()`)

Comment: @TimBüthe performance is rarely an issue, but that's no excuse to go writing sloppy code. Nobody had mentioned the fact that `:gt` would slow down the selection, so I saw no problem posting it as new info to the topic.

Comment: @Joe: I wouldn't say that's sloppy code. Its precise and readable and the optimization you suggest could be made inside jQuery, if it has that big of an effect. However, I can't see any performance gain in this little test I wrote: http://jsfiddle.net/timbuethe/svzAV/. Am I missing something here? Is the DOM structure to simple?

Answer (score 0):

```
var $auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {

    while ($('div').length > 20) {
        $('div:last-child').remove();
    }

    $autoUpdate();
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds for new items
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($articleCount > 20) {            
        $('div:last-child').remove();
        $articleCount = $('div').length;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited for simplicity:

```
$('div').each(function(count){
    if(count >= 20){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: You could simplify this: The [each function](http://api.jquery.com/each/) has two parameters and the first is the index, so your count var is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `:gt()` selector to find the elements in one fell swoop.

```
var $auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {
    var nToDelete = $('div').length - 20; // Calculate how many there are to delete...    
    if(nToDelete > 0) $('div:gt(" + nToDelete + ")').remove(); // and delete them.
    $autoUpdate();
}, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var remove21 = function() {
    if ($('div').length > 20) {
        $('div:nth-child(21)').remove();
        remove21();
    }
}

var $auto_refresh = setInterval(function () {

    remove21();

    $autoUpdate();
}, 10000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds for new items
```